# Estoy haciendo una app y me gustaria saber que version de ireports es compatible con el jdk 17

Tags: ireport

Tengo estas estos plugis pero netbeans no me permite agregarlos son los siguientes: iReport 4.7.1.nmb,jassperReport components pluging 4.7.1, jassperReport extendicions.nmb, jassperserver pluging 4.7.1.nmb

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.